# 5 min video taken by LG G5 is corrupted. Anything to do?

Tags: video, video-recording, lg-g5

I have an LG G5, and I recently took a video of 5 minutes with it (the maximum) which appeared to be corrupted.

The phone stopped the video alone since it arrived to the maximum recording time, and started saving - something that took some pretty long minutes.
After a while of not touching my phone (to not accidentally interrupt the saving) I wanted to watch the video and realized it's corrupted and can't be open.

In the file explorer, I found two files in the format of `DATE_TIME.mp4` (1.6GB) and `DATE_TIME_temp.mp4` (0KB).

Any possible (free) way to fix this video?
How can I make sure it won't happen next time?

Thanks!

*Note: If relevant - not rooted, stock rom, latest update.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP4 Fixer

> [MP4 Fixer on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smamolot.mp4fix)

This used to be a common problem with Screen Recorders that didn't save the information of recorded videos correctly. Using MP4 Fixer i could read the video and fix the duration information allowing normal viewing.

Comment: It worked, but unfortunately it costs money to save the video :(

Comment: This app works by cutting the videos last second or two off, Usually this can be achieved by using another video editor, be careful when trying to edit the video on android because it usually crashes the application if you don't trim enough off, It's like the video has finished but the application is still trying to read the last 1 second of it, you need to end the trim right before the video has finished

Comment: Didn't knew that! I'll try that in the next days on my computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, try some converters from play store. It's hard to name a converter because some of them checks the file for errors before converting them and ignores if they can't convert it. Try Freemake video converter on PC first. It's a commercial software so make sure that it helps before buying it, use a free trial. There are many open source alternatives as well, you can search for them in sourceforge, github etc. iTunes is the last option, if you have an iDevice.

Another tip: Try to play the file with VLC on PC, and an error message may pop up. It might say what's actually wrong with the file.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Copy that file to a PC and use a video converter to convert it to a different format, such as .mov or .avi
You'll be able to enjoy your movie after conversion. You can convert the working video back to .mp4 too if you wish to.

Comment: The file is corrupted, it won't convert to another just like that..

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. Conversions can restore such damaged files in most cases. You may not be able to open the 1.6 GB file, but go ahead and convert it. The generated new file will work. Knowledge on file systems such as CRCs is required to explain how it works. Go ahead and convert it!

Comment: I tried it before my previous comment. If you have a specific software recommendation for doing that, I'd be glad to know!